# WPF items control - item-by-item popup "hover" effect

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an ItemsControl and I would like to display a popup alongside each item as the mouse moves around the control. This is where I've got to so far:-

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <Border x:Name="border" Background="AliceBlue">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="X" />

                <Popup x:Name="ElementPopup"
                       StaysOpen="False"
                       Placement="Right"
                       PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=border}"
                       SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Border Background="Orange" Width="50" Height="50">
                        <TextBlock Text="Popup!" />
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="border"
                        Property="Background"
                        Value="Yellow" />
                <Setter TargetName="ElementPopup"
                        Property="IsOpen"
                        Value="true" />
            </Trigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" Width="100">  
   <sys:String>X</sys:String>
   <sys:String>X</sys:String>
   <sys:String>X</sys:String>
</ItemsControl>
```

As it stands, the popup appears when I first hover over an item, but then it remains in place and I have to click outside of the popup to get rid of it.

I need it to work more like a tooltip, with the popups appearing and disappearing as the mouse moves across the different items. Am I on the right lines with the above XAML or should I be looking at a different approach, e.g. using a ToolTip? (Bear in mind that the real popup will contain a handful of controls that the user can interact with).

Comment: At what point do you require the Popup to disappear?

Comment: Never mind, it was as simple as changing `StaysOpen` to "True". Now, the popup closes when the mouse is no longer over the placement target control or the popup, which is exactly what I wanted. I find it this a little puzzling though, as the help says "when True, the Popup stays open until explicitly closed by setting IsOpen to false". I can only assume that the Trigger is implicitly setting this to false when the condition ("IsMouseOver") is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tweaked your code a little and it works(though the approach is not good):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <Border x:Name="border" Background="AliceBlue">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" />

                <Popup x:Name="ElementPopup" IsOpen="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},Path=IsMouseOver,Mode=OneWay}"
                   StaysOpen="True"
                   Placement="Right"
                   PlacementTarget="{x:Null}"  Focusable="False"
                   SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Border Background="Orange" Width="50" Height="50">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding }" Focusable="False" />
                    </Border>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="border"
                    Property="Background"
                    Value="Yellow" />                   
            </Trigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>    
<ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" Width="100">
    <sys:String>X</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Y</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Z</sys:String>
</ItemsControl>
```

***Output:***

[image: img1]

[image: img2]